# Online encyclopedia of categories?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, online-resources

Being new to categories and mostly interested in specific categories such as the reverse derivative category, I'm wondering if there are any resources like the one for integer sequences and how might one find examples of a specific category.

Comment: This is subtle. For any topological space the sheaves of commutative groups on it form a category. You can never enumerate them, but there do exist interesting examples one should look into.

Comment: There's a database of ring theory https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/ maintained by @rschwieb; I think very similar organisation would be good for encyclopedia of categories.

Comment: Somewhat similar question on [math.se] from 2016: [Category Theory Zoo](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1639034). (At the moment no answer - but at least a few comments.) The other question linked there is more recent - but with no replies: [A comprehensive list of categories](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3928971)

Comment: [Resources for learning Category Theory for an enthusiast](https://github.com/prathyvsh/category-theory-resources)

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage

Comment: This should be CW, since it's basically asking for a big list

Comment: An integer sequence is a specific quantitative thing that remains after its generating process has been erased, so it is reasonable to find equivalent sequences and be led to conjectures about their processes. Categories aren't like that: they are usually designed to be explicit about the way they arise, so are not "accidentally" equivalent.

Comment: I suppose that there could be an analogue of *Counterexamples in Topology* (by Lynn Arthur Steen and J. Arthur Seebach, Springer 1978 & Dover 1995). However, **category theory is an intellectually structured subject** unlike General Topology.

Comment: @PaulTaylor What's an intellectually structured subject?

Comment: @ElizabethHenning. This margin is not wide enough to demonstrate how intellectually structured category theory is.